# File upload problems with php copy($_FILES not working

Tags: php, ajax

**Update**

So I think I've tracked it down to the file not being available:

I've checked the ownership of the folders for uploads and for tmp (above doc root).  Both seem to have the correct ownership as does the upload.php file

I've checked the $_FILES and it shows

> ```
>         [name] => sampleImage3.jpg
>         [type] => image/jpeg
>         [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpypdbTb
>         [error] => 0
>         [size] => 19791
> ```

So the file is being loaded into the tmp folder

However when I try a

> copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$uploadFile);

where

tmp_name is mnt/storage/vhosts/domain.com/tmp/phpypdbTb
uploadFile is uploads/sampleImage3.jpg

it throws a

Warning: copy(uploads/sampleImage3.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Any ideas how to debug and figure out what's going on?

---

**Original**

I want upload a file via ajax.

Html is

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
        <div class='preview'>
            <img src="" id="img" width="100" height="100">
        </div>
        <div >
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
        </div>
    </form> </div>
```

JavaScript is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#but_upload").click(function(){

        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = jQuery('#file')[0].files;

        if(files.length > 0 ){
            fd.append('file',files[0]);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/upload.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response != 0){
                        console.log(response);
                        //jQuery(".preview img").show(); // Display image element
                    }else{
                        alert('file not uploaded');
                    }
                },
            });
        }else{
            alert("Please select a file.");
        }
    });
});
```

which loads upload.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){

    /* Getting file name */
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $location = "/uploads";
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($location,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType);

/*    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";
*/

    /* Valid extensions */
    $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","JPG");
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'$location/$filename');


    $response = 0;
    /* Check file extension */
  //  if(in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $valid_extensions)) {
        /* Upload file */
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'$location/$filename')){
            $response = $location;
        }
    //}

    echo $response;

}

echo 0;
```

The ajax call works no problem and I can even print_r the FILES variable

> Array (
> [file] => Array
> (
> [name] => Organ Pipes and SGW.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpQxJK34 [error] => 0
> [size] => 373852
> )

However the file won't upload.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to be calling `move_uploaded_file` twice. First time is after `$valid_extensions` is set. Second time is in the `if` right after `$response` is set to zero. Try commenting out that `if` block where the second move is.

Comment: I removed the second move_upload_file and it made no difference

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting turned on as well as error logging so any errors will get logged. Since you're calling this from Ajax you wouldn't see any errors if they were happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your location is an absolute path `/uploads` and I think you can find it like this

```
cd /uploads;
ls -la
```

And you should see it 
But if upload directory is in your project or in the same place of your php file you need to change `/uploads` to `./uploads`

Comment: I checked the path and it's correct - however to be sure I gave it the full path:  getcwd()."/uploads